# Add items to combobox as checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, combobox

Hello I am using XAML/WPF to create a Combobox and then using an XML to populate it

Using the suggestion below this is my updated code and now it works!!

This is my  XAML using the suggestions given below

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="customer_comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,259,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" SelectionChanged="customer_comboBox_SelectionChanged" >
         <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

This is my XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ComboBox>
  <Customer name="John">
    <Data>
      <System>Linux</System>
    </Data>
  </Customer>
  <Customer name="Fernando">
    <Data>
      <System>Microsoft</System>
      <System>Mac</System>
    </Data>
  </Customer>
</ComboBox>
```

And this is the code that is used to populate the customer_comboBox

```cs
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +@"\comboBox.xml");
 XmlNodeList customerList = doc.SelectNodes("ComboBox/Customer");
 List<string> customers = new List<string>();

 foreach (XmlNode node in customerList)
 {
     customers.Add(child.InnerText);
 }
 customer_comboBox.ItemsSource = customers;
```

All this works but I would like to have the added items inside the Combobox be in the form of a checklist
I done it through the XAML by adding Checkbox items manually but since I am populating the combobox automatically by reading the XML I like to do it through code. I assume I need to do some type of Data Binding but I do not know how and the answers I seen here are a few years old which reference DataSource which its not a Combobox attribute anymore

Comment: Can not you use databinding or something?

Comment: I suggest you to use an listbox with checkbox items.

Comment: Is it WPF/xaml that you're using ? If so it should be possible to do via combobox controltemplate and bindings. You would still need to populate some model with names, and then do binding list e.g. customer_combobox.ItemsSource = listOfValues;

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis yes I am using WPF/XAML. How do you do controltemplate ?

Comment: @Fernando my bad, it's datatemplate you need. ControlTemplate is more for triggers.

Comment: @Fernando: What do you want to data bind to? Or why do you need a checkbox?

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis I want a checkbox because I then want to send the selected items to a server

Comment: foreach(var item in ComboBox.Items) { if (item is CheckBox && (CheckBox)item).IsChecked) {string val = ((CheckBox)item).Content; }}} or something similar. Would need to know more to give better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way would be :
in XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="customer_comboBox" ...all other themings...>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

For simplicity created data model class called Customer

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then your method would be like

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) +@"\comboBox.xml");
 XmlNodeList customerList = doc.SelectNodes("ComboBox/Customer");

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>()

 foreach (XmlNode node in customerList)
 {
   customers.Add(new Customer(){ Name = node.Attributes["name"].InnerText });
 }

customer_comboBox.ItemsSource = customers;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked!. Only edits i had to do was on the XAML I just used CheckBox Content="{Binding}" and inside my method I used a string list instead

Answer (score 0):

First, create a business class:

```
public class Customer: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Property to build to IsChecked of CheckBox
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the checkbox will look like this (you may databind it later; although if you want to dynamically add/delete items from the `ComboBox` during runtime, my advice is to use something other than `IList` as a databound `ItemsSource`, for example some implementation of `ObservableCollection`)

```
    <ComboBox Name="cbx">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                       Width="20" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Width="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Here is how you populate the ComboBox with data:

```
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        // populate list instead of ComboBox from xml data source here...

        // then set the list as source
        cbx.ItemsSource = customers;
```

Later, to get selected items:

```
 List<Customer> selectedCustomers = ((List<Customer>)cbx.ItemsSource)
     .Where(a => a.IsSelected).ToList();
```

Comment: I used the implementation you showed me above. But the Combobox still not populating. And to answer your question I do want this ComboBox to dynamically updated during runtime. Because my real plan is to read my xml and if "John" is selected populate "Linux" within the a ComboBox. But if "Fernando" is selected populate"Microsoft" and "Mac" on that ComboBox.